# function call from another function in php and php script should run backgound

Tags: php, function

I have created a class `A()` with two functions i.e `a()` and `b()`.

Function `a()` have a condition `if(state==true)` then break operation.

If the condition is false, then it should call function `b()`.

Function `b()` will call again function `a()` untill function's `a()` condition gets true.

Below is my code :

```
class name
{
    public function a($id)
    {
        if() {} else {
            b($id);
        }
    }

    public function b($id)
    {
        sleep(10);
        a();
    }
}

$id = 4;
$oba = new name();
$oba->a($id);
```

Comment: Have you attempted this yourself? It seems you have good pseudo-code, translating to PHP should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

hi hussain 
are you wanted to do something like this?

```
<?php
    class name{

        public function a($id)
        {
            if($id==4){
                echo"condition statisfied";
                return true;
            }
        }

    }
$id= 0;
$a_obj = new name();
while ( $id<= 4) {
     $a_obj->a($id);
     echo "id count :".$id."<br>";  
     $id++;
}
?>
```

this is the efficeint way to perform what you wanted to do.
and for running script in background you can refer this [link](https://devdojo.com/articles/how-to-run-a-php-script-in-background)
and please explain question properly.

soo far you don't have a function called `a()` as your taking it as a constructor.